# how sync Google and app calendar

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'am trying to use google calendar in calendar application. I want to let user syncronize his google calendar events in app calendar. This is my code

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
     onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
     onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>                                                    
<script>function handleClientLoad()
        {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
        }
        function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
                discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                scope: SCOPES
            }).then(function(){
                loadEvents();
            })
        }
function loadEvents()
        {
            gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                'calendarId': '<?=$option['selected']?>',
                'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
                'showDeleted': false,
                'singleEvents': true,
                'maxResults': 10,
                'orderBy': 'startTime'
            }).then(function(response) {    
                var gEvents = response.result.items;                            
            })
```

For me it works fine but for users shows authorization error. How can I fix it. I need to send authorization key for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having issues with authorization, you can check [these](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials) points. Your error was specified in the documentation and can be resolved by the following:

> - Get a new access token using the long-lived refresh token.
> - If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described    in [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth).
> - If you are seeing this for a service account, check that you have    successfully completed all the steps in the [service account page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).